# how to resize picture on browser

Tags: html

I need to set the background image of my website to this picture.

[image]

However, when I look at the page, I see white space on that page as illustrated below:

[image]

I want the picture to cover the whole space, and when I open the site in any computer it must show the same. Finally I could not write text in the middle part of the center of the image. Not on top, but in the middle center of picture. Here is  what I have so far

[image]

I need to  have this text on the page in the middle part. Not in high part of page, but in the middle. Here is a short fragment of code that I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ka-ge" lang="ka-ge" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>
#links { 
  postiton:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 4800px; 
    font-size:50px;
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
    z-index:-90;
}
#test a {
    float: right;
}
a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: light-blue;
    a {text-decoration:none;}
}
</style>
<style>

a {text-decoration:none;}
</style>

<body    >


<a href="eng/index.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"> </a>
<a href="russ/index.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="90" height="90"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="90" height="90"/></a>
<img src="11.gif" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<div id="links">

<a href=" index.html " >მთავარი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ბაკურიანი.html ">ბაკურიანი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" გუდაური.html ">გუდაური </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ზღვა.html ">ზღვა </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" კახეთი.html ">კახეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" სვანეთი.html ">სვანეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ვარძია.html ">ვარძია </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ქართლი.html ">ქართლი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ძველი_თბილისი.html ">ძველი_თბილისი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" დაკავშირება.html ">კონტაქტი </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you want the CSS `background-image` property.

Comment: look at this cool background explanations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image

Comment: but here is very short explanation,how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a little modification in your code as below:

```
</head>
< style>
#links { 

position:absolute;
margin: 0 auto; 
top: 50%;       //centers vertically
left: 50%;     //centers horizontally
width: 4800px; 
font-size:50px;
clear: both; 
display: block;
z-index:-90;
}
```

...

and in body tag as well:

```
<body background="11.gif">
```

above body tag sets your image in the background. You can resize your images i.e. either stretch or compress them using "height" and "width" attributes in the < img> tags to set their sizes.
Now you can place whatever text,link or other images over your background image.

Try it!